# Emacs matlab mode key binding for running tests

Tags: unit-testing, matlab, emacs

I am using Emacs + [matlab-mode](http://matlab-emacs.sourceforge.net/) as my Matlab development environment. I also have [MTEST](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/03/mtest-a-unit-test-harness-for-matlab-code/) installed together with Matlab to run my unit tests - what I want to do now is to have a key binding that runs the tests from the current file in the matlab-shell I constantly have opened around (`M-x matlab-shell`).

What I have until now is:

```
; Runs the unit tests available in the current buffer
(defun run-matlab-test ()
(interactive)
(matlab-shell-run-command (concat "runtests "
                (car (split-string (buffer-name) "\\.")))))

; Bind "C-c l" to running unit tests in matlab-mode
(defun map-run-matlab-test-keys ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c l") 'run-matlab-test))

(add-hook 'matlab-mode-hook 'map-run-matlab-test-keys)
```

What I need to do is in the `run-matlab-test` function to have a way of calling the `runtests` command with the parameter provided by the `(buffer-name)` command and all this should happen in the matlab shell I mentioned above. Any hints ?

**Edit**: I managed to get it working by calling `matlab-shell-run-command`. The caveat here is that it only works if the starting sequence is: open your `unit-test.m` file, from that file run `M-x matlab-shell` (this way matlab starts with the current working directory in the tests directory) and then you can use the above binding.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid your caveat above, you could probably issue a cd to matlab, before calling runtest, by doing something like the following (untested):

```
(defun run-matlab-test ()
  (interactive)
  (matlab-shell-run-command (concat "cd " (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))))
  (matlab-shell-run-command (concat "runtests "
                            (car (split-string (buffer-name) "\\.")))))
```